# Codename One - multilist values

Tags: codenameone

## Problem

On one Form I have a Multilist where each item has a "name" and an "ID number". I'd like my app to do the following:

After I select an item, it will go to the "profile" screen and then it will display all the information about that person, based on the "ID number" that I will get from the Storage.

## Question

How can I get the information from the Multilist item I just clicked?
And then, how can I save that info so I can use it in the "before show (Profile screen)" so I can retrieve the info from Storage.
Thnaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest you use a MultiButton instead of Multilist, then you can add actionEvent to individual element.

You can save individual element into static variables in the actionEvent and use it in the before show of your profile form. For example:

Declare this globally:

```
private static String UserName = "";
```

And initialize it as follows:

```
Container content = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
content.setScrollableY(true);
for (int i = 0; i < YourItemsLength; i++) {
        final MultiButton mb = new MultiButton("Blablabla");
        mb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                UserName = mb.getTextLine1(); // or anything you want it to be
                //show the profile form here
            }
        });
        content.addComponent(mb);
}
content.revalidate();
```

In the beforeShow() of profile, call UserName and you should be able to use the value. Do the same for all the values you need.

Comment: The code should be under the "Main_onCreate" method, right?

Comment: No, it should be under postShow() if your form was created with GUI Builder.

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with Diamonds answer and I think that's the best/simplest way to create a list of items. However, if you do still want to use `MultiList` you need to implement a `ListModel` or use `DefaultListModel`.

From your question I assume you just used the `MultiList` and filled out the values?

In that case when there is an action event on the list you can just get the instance of the list the invoke `Map m = (Map)myList.getSelectedItem();`

The map should return key/value pairs containing your data. You can have hidden keys within that data simple by naming them differently from rendererd list elements so you can have something like "id" as the key.